# É possível, no MySQL, atualizar as informações de uma coluna em diversas linhas duplicadas, deixando apenas uma linha com o valor original?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Por exemplo, tenho diversas linhas em uma tabela (que puxei de um XML de produtos do google, então o mesmo produto é apresentado diversas vezes, cada um para um tamanho da roupa/produto) que são referenciadas para o mesmo item, apenas com diferença de tamanho do produto, quantidade e código SKU. Nesta tabela, tenho uma coluna que determina se o produto é apresentado ou não no sistema (0 ou 1). O que eu gostaria de fazer era rodar uma query que verificaria os itens duplicados, alterando o parametro dessa coluna que disponibiliza a visulização, escondendo todos os itens duplicados, deixando apenas um com o valor original.

Eu consegui atingir algo similar com a query abaixo:

```
DELETE a FROM sis_produto_xml a LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MIN(ID) id, sku, nome FROM sis_produto_xml GROUP BY nome) b ON a.id = b.id AND a.sku = b.sku AND a.nome = b.nome WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

O problema dessa query é que ela deleta o produto, e depois o XML baixa o mesmo produto novamente, ou seja, é um trabalho que não tem fim. Escondendo o produto através do parametro da tabela (com um update ao invés do delete) isso não iria ocorrer.

Valeu galera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percebi que a query do post deleta itens únicos, mas consegui resolver o problema da seguinte maneira:

```
DELETE table FROM table INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(id) AS lastid, column FROM table WHERE column IN ( SELECT column FROM table GROUP BY nome HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) GROUP BY column ) duplic ON duplic.column = table.column WHERE table.column2 < duplic.lastid;
```

Valeu comunidade!

Answer (score 0):

É só você alterar a `query` que você havia citado para `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE a
   SET apresentado = 0
  FROM sis_produto_xml a
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(ID) id,
                         sku,
                         nome
                    FROM sis_produto_xml
                   GROUP BY nome) b ON a.id = b.id
                                   AND a.sku = b.sku
                                   AND a.nome = b.nome
 WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Depois de penar fazendo alguns testes entendi essa alteração e consegui fazer funcionar.

Comment: @thierryrene deu certo usando essa resposta então?

Comment: + / -, acabei precisando fazer outra query, porque esta deletava resultados únicos, postei a resposta! Obrigado @Sorack !